# Installing Oracle 11g on Ubuntu Linux server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, oracle11g, putty, winscp

I have downloaded linux oracle 11g on windows and want to copy it to ubuntu linux server and install oracle on linux server.

I am using Winscp and putty.

OS i am using is windows 7,but copying from windows to linux takes long and session expires.

Is there any way to avoid what i am doing and install oracle 11g on linux server directly.

I am new to this so please help..

Comment: Why do you want to use Ubuntu? Is it important for you?

Comment: Hi, yeah kind of because company says..client use ubuntu

Comment: If I were you I would try to convince them to use a rpm-based Linux, like: CentOS, RHEL, Oracle Linux. You will have less problems in future.

Comment: Will pass on the suggestion..But as of now is there a solution to my query?

Comment: Do you use pscp to copy files? if the session fails you can try to use fpt or http read [this article](http://moo.nac.uci.edu/~hjm/HOWTO_move_data.html) about this topic or directly from ubunut using wget you can download the oracle installation files.

Comment: You aren't saying what version of ubuntu server you are using but there are many guides available for doing this. Such as: http://www.makina-corpus.org/blog/howto-install-oracle-11g-ubuntu-linux-1204-precise-pangolin-64bits

Comment: @mikea I guess the problem now is that the OP can't upload the oracle installation files.

Comment: ubuntu version is 12.04.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check FileZilla. You can use it over cross platform and resume your uploads.

Comment: swapnil Hi can you tell me how to download through putty? using wget command?

Comment: I have not used wget. I use scp for unix to unix, ftp or winscp for unix/windows.